# Create new columns pandas dataframe from function, fixing length ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, data-augmentation

I have a dataset with a column containing a quote (string column in a dataframe).

I'm using spacy to extract the named entities and their types into a new column.
So, my function should take the first quote, extract entity names from that row and add them into a new column, and extract the entity types and add them into a new column

My function currently looks like this:

```
def find_named_entities(df, quote):

  entity_text_list = []
  entity_label_list = []
  quotes = politifact_df.source_quote.to_list()
  print("quotes:", quotes)
  
  nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
  for quote in quotes:
    doc = nlp(quote)
    for entity in doc.ents:
      entity_text_list.append(entity.text)
      entity_label_list.append(entity.label)

  df["entity_names"] = entity_text_list
  df["entity_label"] = entity_label_list
  
  return df
```

and I run with:

```
politifact2_df = find_named_entities(politifact_df, politifact_df.source_quote)
```

But the problem with this is that the lists `entity_text_list` and `entity_label_list` is that it is trying to give each separate item in the list as its own column, which won't work because the length of the column will be greater than the length of the dataframe.

Can someone point out my mistake and how I could fix it?

I've looked around for similar questions and found that most of them aren't creating a new column from a function and aren't dealing with this ValueError

Comment: What's your example input and output?

Comment: @CamiloMartínez Example input is a string containing an article headline, and output should be the entities that space recognizes contained in separate columns